# Hibernate calling procedure having mutliple result set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I am connecting to mysql using hibernate. I have a database procedure which returns multiple result set.

`DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer_meta()
   BEGIN
   SELECT area_code,description  FROM area;
   SELECT category_code,description  FROM category;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;`

As per [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) which says

`You cannot use stored procedures with Hibernate unless you follow some procedure/function rules. If they do not follow those rules they are not usable with Hibernate. If you still want to use these procedures you have to execute them via session.connection().`

**As my requirement is something like this, (Multiple result set ) How can I achieve this with hibernate ?. How can I execute them via session.connection() as described in docs ?**

I have already tried using storedProcedureQuery but I get error `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'area_code' not found.` On this line in below code `List<Object[]> secondList = query.getResultList();`.

```
@Repository
public class CustomerMetaDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomerMetaModel getCustomerMetaData() {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("get_customer_meta");
        List<Object[]> objList = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println(objList.get(0)[0]);
        System.out.println(objList.get(0)[1]);
        if (query.hasMoreResults()) {
            List<Object[]> secondList = query.getResultList();
            System.out.println(secondList.get(0)[0]);
            System.out.println(secondList.get(0)[1]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a view instead and connect the queries using `union`.

Comment: @PeterRader: I cannot touch the procedure as it is maintained by some other vendors.

Comment: Hi did you got the solution fof multiset result

Answer (score 0):

- I believe we cannot use hibernate where the stored procedure is returning multiple resultsets. Instead of hibernate, you should use JDBC.